# Animator Panel in Unity - Where is "Entry"?

Tags: unity

I am following a tutorial on Unity, and I saw a screenshot like the following:

[image]

When I reproduced the steps of the tutorial, I realized that the green "Entry" box was not present on my screen. I have been thinking why this could be and the only reasons that I could think of are:

1. The tutorial skipped a step
2. I have something misconfigured
3. In the latest version of Unity that box has been erased or replaced

Which one is it? Did I forget a 4th option?

PS: If it is option #3, could someone explain me what was this feature for, and what has it been replaced with?

**UPDATE** I am using Unity 4.6.2f1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [new feature of Unity 5.0](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/06/26/shiny-new-animation-features-in-unity-5-0/).

> In Unity 5, we’ve added **Entry** and **Exit** nodes to StateMachines. There
> are used during State Machine Transitions.
>
> **Entry**:  When you transition to a StateMachine, the animation system
> will evaluate the Entry node and branch to the destination that its
> conditions meet.
>
> **Exit**: When going to the Exit node, the animation system will look at
> the outgoing StateMachine transitions and branch to the proper
> destination.

If you are using the latest version of Unity as you say, then that leaves options one or two.

Comment: I am using 4.6.2, as it is the latest available on http://unity3d.com/unity/download . I thought version 5 was not yet available. Was I wrong?

Comment: Which tutorial are you following?

Comment: http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/2d-roguelike

Comment: But I am using 4.6.2, and the feature is not there...

Comment: "This video series was filmed in Unity 5, but is compatible with Unity 4.6 as well". Looks like you either don't have to worry about the Entry box being there, or they were wrong.